# building static libraries independently giving error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

now its giving error that #include  not found. Folder from where i add the libraries is placed on desktop. I also set the header search path to that folder, cant figure out what is the problem. help me out!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag is only available on Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 and later.

Removing the flag completely is the same as defining it, default is no ARC.